# Given start and end year for an event create label for each year

Tags: ms-access

I've been given a table with event name and the start date and end date for someone who has participated in an the event.

```
ID | Event | StartYear | EndYear
----------------------------------
1  | Race  |   2001    | 2005
2  | Race  |   2003    | 2004
3  | Race  |   2004    | 2004
```

I need to break out the years that someone participated in the event so that for each year that someone participated in the event create a new row and append the year to the Event name. So it would look like this:

```
ID | Event 
--------------
1  | Race 2001
1  | Race 2002
1  | Race 2003
1  | Race 2004
1  | Race 2005 
2  | Race 2003
2  | Race 2004
3  | Race 2004
```

I originally thought doing individual queries for each year and then unioning them back together but that wouldn't be scale-able as they add more years. How can I go about doing this in access?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this can be done without creating a table containing all possible years that can occur.

Assuming this table is called `tblYears` and has a field named `Year` that contains values like 2001, 2002, 2003, etc., you can create your desired output with this query, assuming the events are stored in `tblEventParticipations`:

```sql
   SELECT e.ID, e.Event & ' ' & y.Year AS Event
     FROM tblEventParticipations AS e
LEFT JOIN tblYears AS y
       ON (y.Year BETWEEN e.StartYear AND e.EndYear)
```

If you have a year missing in `tblYears` you will also have that row missing from this query. If the entire year range of one event participation is missing, then you will have a single output row for that event participation without the year appended to the event name.

If you want to re-insert this data into `tblEventParticipations` just INSERT it like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblEventParticipations
SELECT ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Tally table is called what you are after. In this case the tallytbl has 1 column "Year" and values 2001,2002,2003,2004,2005

```
select c.ID,c.Event,b.Year 
from giventbl c 
inner join tallytbl b 
on c.startyear <= b.year and c.endyear >= b.year 
order by c.ID, b.year
```